# Code stops working when transferred into function?

Tags: python, function

I am facing the issue of converting a python class into a function to be used as a helper for another main code. Below is the excerpt of the code and its comparisons:

```
sensor_data = {'temperature': 0}
client = mqtt.Client()
client.loop_start()

try:
    while True:
        temperature = sense.get_temperature()
        print(u"Temperature: {:g}".format(temperature))
        sensor_data['temperature'] = temperature

        # Sending temperature data to ThingsBoard
        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry', json.dumps(sensor_data), 1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

But when I tried transferring to a function to call, given that "data" is a random variable to be fed into the function:

```
def getTemperature(data)
    sensor_data = {'temperature': 0}
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.loop_start()
    
    try:
        while True:
            print(u"Temperature: {:g}".format(data))
            sensor_data['temperature'] = data

            # Sending temperature data to ThingsBoard
            client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry', json.dumps(sensor_data), 1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    client.loop_stop()
    client.disconnect()
    
    return data
```

The function fails to receive any errors but it is not outputting any print statements on the console or anything. Is there a reason why this occurs?

Comment: Are you calling that function anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I'd call from main() where getTemperature(38.7)

Comment: Get rid of the `while True` loop!  The standalone routine is constantly getting a new temperature value and publishing the new value.  Your new function wants to publish it only once, because it is being transferred into the function.  You'll be spinning publishing the same data!

Answer (score 0):

```
def getTemperature(data):
    sensor_data = {'temperature': 0}
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.loop_start()
    try:
        while True:
            print(u"Temperature: {:g}".format(data))
            sensor_data['temperature'] = data
            # Sending temperature data to ThingsBoard
            client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry', json.dumps(sensor_data), 1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    client.loop_stop()
    client.disconnect()

    return data

getTemperature(5)
```

try this.